# req.getParameter returns null

Tags: javascript, java, servlets

Im trying to get values from my request but it return null. What is the problem?

This is my form:

```
    <form class="register-form">
        <input class="name" type="text" placeholder="name"/>
        <input class="password" type="password" placeholder="password"/>
        <button id="register">create</button>
    </form>
```

My post method:

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        String name = req.getParameter("name"); 
        if (Objects.isNull(projectService.getByName(name))) {
            logger.info("Registration new project " + name); //NAME == NULL ???
            String password = req.getParameter("password");
            int budget = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("budget"));

         ...

        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resp.getWriter().write("Success");
    }
```

And JS part:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button#register").click(function () {
        var name = $("form.register-form input.name").val();
        var password = $("form.register-form input.password").val();
        if (name == '' || password == '') {
            alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
        }  else {
            var projectRegistration = {
                projectName: name,
                projectPassword: password
            };
            $.post("registration", projectRegistration, function (data) {
                if (data === 'Success') {
                    $("form")[0].reset();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Im using Tomcat ver 8.5.56

Comment: There was a typo in your JS code. The if condition has an extra || operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At JS code you are building an object **projectRegistration** which is passed to post request. This object has keys **projectName** and **projectPassword** which should be used inside the servlet:

```
String name = req.getParameter("projectName");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works fo me!

Comment: Great! But I think you should also consider the other answer too, since the name attribute in the inputs are also missing.

Comment: @CarlosBazilio - You have a heart of gold.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the problem is that you are not passing any parameter with the name, `name` because you do not have an input field with the name, `name`.

Replace

```
<input class="name" type="text" placeholder="name"/>
```

with

```
<input class="name" type="text" placeholder="name" name="name"/>
```

Comment: I think that my answer and yours are together the cause, don't you think? The request is made by JS code, which passes the projectRegistration object. This object doesn't have a field name also.

Comment: @CarlosBazilio - You are right. Thanks for asking OP to consider this answer as well.